# Error in downloading Jupyter Notebook as PDF via LateX

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, download, latex

**[Working on Windows 11, Python 3.9.7]**

I just installed the `MikTex Console`, and the settings show that keys `xelatex` and `xelatex-dev` are present (see bottom of image below):

[image]

Now, in a *markdown cell* of a `Jupyter Notebook`, I introduce an image (stored on my personal Desktop):

```
![1%20cbGPF1go7MMWvHif7-2hAw.png](attachment:1%20cbGPF1go7MMWvHif7-2hAw.png)
```

When I run the cell, I get the perfect image in the Notebook:

[image]

So, everything seems to behave well, **BUT**, when I just want to save the Notebook as `PDF via LateX`,as indicated in the image below:

[image]

**then I get a `500 : Internal Server Error`, saying**:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:
```

Does somebody know what is this "`xelatex notebook.tex -quiet`" command ? How is it related to LateX? Is it something missing in the settings of the `MikTex Console`? Do you know how could I fix this kind of error?

Comment: What I did was to print jupyter notebook in navigator and save file as pdf

Answer (score 0):

the provided error is quite succinct, there should have been things after the `command:`, something like

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
```

Responding to your questions anyway, the `xelatex notebook.tex -quiet` is the command run when you click "save as PDF via LaTeX", XeLaTeX itself is an enhancment of LaTeX (which itself enhanced TeX).
The main objective of XeLaTeX is to provide better encoding and font support than LaTeX does. [see here](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/xelatex).

On how to fix the error, I would recommand to make a "save as LaTeX (.tex)" and try running `xelatex notebook.tex` directly in a console. It should show you the exact error that is happening. [This issue](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1099) on jupyter GitHub makes me guess it is either a dependency problem or a unsupported syntax problem.

If needed you can comment/update your question with more specific logs

Comment: Well, the strangest thing is that there is nothing after `command:` the text stops there. Other than that, I made a "save as LaTeX (.tex)", as you recommended, but I am very far from being a competent user of `LaTeX` ; so, I have the `TeX` file open in front of my eyes, with some tabs above (`File`, `Edit`, `Search`, ...) which tell me nothing at all,  and I realize that I don't know what it means "running `xelatex notebook.tex` directly in a console". What kind of "console" would I have to open, and should I have to copy/paste that `TeX` file ? sorry for my dullness...

Comment: After doing quite a bit of manipulation and research, the only conclusion I can come to is that `Jupyter Notebooks` do not support the inclusion of remote images in `Markdown` type cells: something else has to be done. It is kind of a shame...

Comment: By running `xelatex notebook.tex` I kinda assumed you used LaTeX at least once. Miktex provide a console (cmd.exe) (the button is visible on your first screen bottom left) which allow to run some commands. You can navigate to your file using `cd path/to/file`, and run the xelatex command there. Also It might suites your needs better to export in pdf via html as it does not require the use of latex. Also as a workaround, the syntax `from IPython.display import Image
Image("image.png")` should work

Comment: Thanks, Corentin, I need to take my time to learn how to do this... (By the way, I tried export in pdf via html, but this produces a deplorable format with lines cut where it should not be.)